# Array : how to get file position by natural order sorting?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop

I want to sort the files located in a folder, in a naturel order.
The files are : "1-Test1.docx", "2-Test2.docx", "3-Test3.docx", "10-Test10.docx".

When I use the following :

```
for( $i= 0 ; $i <= 4; $i++ ){
    $nomfichier = glob("vendor/templates/part3/*.docx");
    natsort ($nomfichier);
    print_r ($nomfichier);
}
```

I have :

```
Array ( [0] => folder1/folder2/1-Test1.docx [2] => folder1/folder2/2-Test2.docx [3] => folder1/folder2/1-Test3.docx [1] => folder1/folder2/10-Test10.docx )
```

That's okay. But when I try to echo each position, using the same natural order, it gives me the "10-Test10.docx" just after the "1-Test1.docx".

```
    $position = array_search($nomfichier[$i], $nomfichier);
   // echo $nomfichier[$i]. " : ". $position;
```

gives...

```
folder1/folder2/1-Test1.docx : 0 folder1/folder2/10-Test10.docx : 1 folder1/folder2/2-Test2.docx : 2 folder1/folder2/3-Test3.docx : 3
```

Whereas I'd like to have the following result :

```
folder1/folder2/1-Test1.docx : 0 folder1/folder2/2-Test2.docx : 1 folder1/folder2/3-Test3.docx : 2 folder1/folder2/10-Test10.docx : 3
```

How could I do to make it work ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Are you printing using a for loop or foreach loop?

Comment: I use a for loop to print the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening as `natsort` sort the array but key keeps same. so when you are printing value of `0` index, it will print `10-Test10.docx`. To achive this correctly, you can use `array_multisort` with `SORT_NATURAL` flag as below:

```
for( $i= 0 ; $i <= 4; $i++ ){
    $nomfichier = glob("uploads/*.jpeg");
    array_multisort($nomfichier, SORT_NATURAL);
    $position = array_search($nomfichier[$i], $nomfichier);
    echo $nomfichier[$i]. " : ". $position;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Great it's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a for loop the index will override the sorting.
When you for loop and echo $arr[1] it's still the item 1 in the array no matter what the sorting shows.

Foreach on the other hand does not loop indexed and obeys the sorting order.

```
// Your array
$arr = array (
  0 => 'folder1/folder2/1-Test1.docx ',
  2 => 'folder1/folder2/2-Test2.docx ',
  3 => 'folder1/folder2/1-Test3.docx ',
  1 => 'folder1/folder2/10-Test10.docx ',
);

foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
folder1/folder2/1-Test1.docx 
folder1/folder2/2-Test2.docx 
folder1/folder2/1-Test3.docx 
folder1/folder2/10-Test10.docx
```

https://3v4l.org/J3SkA

If you by any reason need to know the index key value then you can use `foreach($arr as $key => $val){` and $key will be the index of the array.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation !